# How to work with elliptic curve SECP256K1 key in Azure Key Vault when the key is used also by a blockchain

Tags: blockchain, private-key, public-key, azure-keyvault, elliptic-curve

I'm wondering how to work with SECP256K1 keys within Azure Key Vault when at the same time the key is also required for account creation on a blockchain.

**WHAT HAS TO BE ACHIEVED**

1. Generate SECP256K1 key pair
2. Use public key for account creation on a blockchain
3. Store private key to Key Vault and use it for signing purposes

**ATTEMPT #1 - GENERATE OUTSIDE KEY VAULT AND IMPORT**

I have generated SECP256K1 key pair outside Key Vault. As a result I have private key and public key available as strings.
My idea was to import the private key to Key Vault with help of Azure SDK for.NET wia following piece of code (ECParameters used are from Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.WebKey.ECParameters namespace):

```
  //this part of code is taken from https://www.scottbrady91.com/C-Sharp/JWT-Signing-using-ECDSA-in-dotnet-Core
  var privateKeyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(privateKey);
  var privateKeyInt =
    new Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger(+1, privateKeyBytes);
  var parameters = SecNamedCurves.GetByName("secp256k1");
  var ecPoint = parameters.G.Multiply(privateKeyInt);
  var privateKeyX = ecPoint.Normalize().XCoord.ToBigInteger()
    .ToByteArrayUnsigned();
  var privateKeyY = ecPoint.Normalize().YCoord.ToBigInteger()
    .ToByteArrayUnsigned();

  //the following part is my code
  var ecParameters = new ECParameters();
  ecParameters.Curve = "P-256K";
  ecParameters.X = privateKeyX;
  ecParameters.Y = privateKeyY;
  ecParameters.D = privateKeyBytes;

  var key = new JsonWebKey(ecParameters);
  JsonWebKeyVerifier.Options options =
    JsonWebKeyVerifier.Options.DenyIncompatibleOperations
    | JsonWebKeyVerifier.Options.DenyExtraneousFields;
  string error = (string) null;

  JsonWebKeyVerifier.VerifyByKeyType(key, options, ref error);

  await client.ImportKeyWithHttpMessagesAsync(vaultBaseUri, name, key);
```

The resulting key for import looks like this (copied from Visual Studio variable view, maybe it's shortened):

```
  {
    "kty": "EC",
    "crv": "P-256K",
    "x": "vSUHj6deEhPI6QeILgfgf2I7VTgmiDon_5nsss560OA",
    "y": "DK8DnzEOv57arN6f4Wou-vXkty7uje0n2xTHgGAehp8",
    "d": "NUpoaEEzWTFVYXBKNWZuRWZNUkVxZkpKY29LWGdMcHpFUnVNQ2E2Wjd0YkNhY2NpQ3N5"
  }
```

Although JsonWebKeyVerifier returns no error and a call to key.IsValid() returns true, the call to Key Vault failed with HTTP 400 Bad Request. I have turn on logging on Key Vault instance and following log appears there (id, username, IP addresses and GUIDs are changed intentionally, I'm not sure what is confidential; I can provide them on demand):

```
{
  "time": "2018-11-28T16:28:05.2034585Z",
  "category": "AuditEvent",
  "operationName": "KeyImport",
  "resultType": "Success",
  "resultDescription": "EC key is not valid - cannot instantiate crypto service.",
  "correlationId": "5682a894-0150-484f-a398-6922efed4458",
  "callerIpAddress": "XX.XX.XXX.XXX",
  "identity": {
    "claim": {
      "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "appid": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/scope": "user_impersonation",
      "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn": "xxx.xxxxxx@xxxxxxxx.com",
      "ipaddr": "XX.XX.XXX.XXX",
      "http://schemas.microsoft.com/claims/authnmethodsreferences": "pwd"
    }
  },
  "properties": {
    "id": "https://xxxxxxx.vault.azure.net/keys/testJK1",
    "clientInfo": "FxVersion/4.6.27019.06 OSName/Windows OSVersion/Microsoft.Windows.10.0.17134. Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClient/3.0.2.0",
    "httpStatusCode": 400,
    "requestUri": "https://xxxxxxxx.vault.azure.net/keys/testJK1?api-version=7.0",
    "isAccessPolicyMatch": true,
    "keyProperties": {
      "type": "EC"
    }
  },
  "resourceId": "/SUBSCRIPTIONS/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/RESOURCEGROUPS/XXXXXX-RG/PROVIDERS/MICROSOFT.KEYVAULT/VAULTS/XXXXXXX",
  "operationVersion": "7.0",
  "resultSignature": "Bad Request",
  "durationMs": "259"
}
```

**ATTEMPT #2 - GENERATE WITHIN KEY VAULT AND EXPORT**

Even if I'm able to generate SECP256K1 EC key within Key Vault, I didn't find how to export its public key part.

*EDIT 11/23/2018*

GetKey method on Azure Key Vault returns JsonWebKey that contains X and Y coordinates.

**QUESTIONS**

1. Is it possible to import SECP256K1 key via Azure SDK for .NET? If yes, could you provide me a link to working example?
2. Am I doing something wrong/insufficent in my code during attempt to import the key to Key Vault?
3. Is it possible to export SECP256K1 public key from Key Vault?
4. Do you have any other idea how to accomplish the achievements described herein before?

*EDIT 11/29/2018*

5. Is there a way how to construct public key from X and Y coordinates (ideally in .NET world)?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Jan

PS: I originally posted this question on [Azure Key Vault blog](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/3ba8cbcc-59a7-4adc-ab69-950f71cc4c8d/how-to-work-with-elliptic-curve-secp256k1-key-used-by-a-blockchain?forum=AzureKeyVault), but here is probably much broader audience. I'll link both sources once it will be answered,

Comment: Are you trying to import the public or the private key? Because the private key is d, the public key is the x,y pair! When I read your question, I got the impression that you are trying to import all at once?

Comment: My intention was to import only private key. Should I import only d (without x and y)? I'll give it a try on Monday (I'm currently out of my computer) and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: yes, and if needed you need to convert it to the correct import format (Base58??)

Comment: Trying to import without X and Y ends with error message:
The property "key" must be a valid JsonWebKey object.

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve a similar scenario, I had an openssh pem format key pair generated using Putty Key Generator which I was able to import into KeyVault using the following code.

```
 var client = new KeyClient(new Uri("https://myKeyVault.vault.azure.net"), new ClientSecretCredential("tenantid", "clientid", "clientSecret"));

 var key = ECDsa.Create();
 key.ImportFromPem(@"-----BEGIN EC PARAMETERS-----
     ....
     -----END EC PARAMETERS-----
     -----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
     ...
     -----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
     ");

 JsonWebKey jwk = new JsonWebKey(key, true);
 await client.ImportKeyAsync("MyKey", jwk);
```

You'll need to setup an app registration and create an access policy in the key vault in order to be able to do the import as described here
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/fetching-secrets-from-key-vault-in-net-console-app